# Passing input arguments to to a bash alias/function

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu-12.04, alias

In bash shell, what is the command to go to a special  directory
based on two input arguments?

The command I want to get executed is this:

```
cd /home/btfoouser/mia_YOCTO/build_4/build/tmp-eglibc/deploy/images/p99/
```

I want to pass `build4` and `p99` as my input arguments to the cd command from the command line.

For example, the command will be `my_cd build_4 p99`, which should get translated to

```
cd /home/btfoouser/mia_YOCTO/build_4/build/tmp-eglibc/deploy/images/p99/
```

I tried:

```
alias my_cd ='cd /home/btfoouser/mia_YOCTO/$1/build/tmp-eglibc/deploy/images/$2'
```

Comment: Please follow this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help) it will be useful to help you to lift your content quality up

Answer (score 3):

Aliases don't parse arguments.  Use a function:

```
my_cd() { cd "/home/btfoouser/mia_YOCTO/$1/build/tmp-eglibc/deploy/images/$2"; }
```

To make the function permanent, put it in your `~/.bashrc` file.

Comment: There is a dirty hack for making aliases take arguments :  `alias my_cd='{ read x y; cd "/home/btfoouser/mia_YOCTO/$x/build/tmp-eglibc/deploy/images/$y"; } <<<'` & then `my_cd "dir1 dir2"` This is of course, not a recommendation, but just for information...

Comment: @anishsane Nice evil hack!